# weird Object Destructuring in Javascript { obj : { } }

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, object-destructuring

I was looking at someone's code of a chrome extension where there is an API `chrome.storage.local.get` which basically takes two parameters: key and callback respectively.
suppose we have a object (named **Highlights**) stored in local storage. if I wanna access that object then I have to pass `'highlights'` as first parameter (i.e. key) to the `chrome.storage.local.get` function.

code should look like :

```js
chrome.storage.local.get('highlights', callback);
```

it works fine but the developer of the extension used a different approach, his code look like :

```js
chrome.storage.local.get({highlights: {} }, callback);
```

Notice the key parameter `{ highlights : {} }` surprisingly it gives the same results.

I just wanna know that what does `{ highlights: {} }` means and why does it works.

some extra information :

**highlights** is an object of arrays.
snapshot of highlights object in `console.log` :
[image: snapshot of console.log of highlights object]

Comment: That's not destructuring. That's an object literal containing a property, `highlights`, set to an empty object.

Comment: [`.get(keys?: string | string[] | object, callback: function)`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#usage): _"`keys`: A single key to get, list of keys to get, or a **dictionary specifying default values** (see description of the object). An empty list or object will return an empty result object. Pass in null to get the entire contents of storage."_

Comment: It's an object with `highlights` as key and an empty object literal `{}` as the key's value.

Answer (score 4):

That's not destructuring. That's an object literal containing a property, `highlights`, set to an empty object.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#type-StorageArea) *(which was harder to find than I would have expected)*:

> **`keys`**
>
> `string | string[] | object` optional
>
> A single key to get, list of keys to get, **or a dictionary specifying default values** (see description of the object). An empty list or object will return an empty result object. Pass in null to get the entire contents of storage.

*(my emphasis)*

So passing in that object is saying: "Give me the `highlights` value from storage, using `{}` as the default if there isn't any."

Comment: I couldn't understand what does above stuff means but last three lines is what I wanted to hear. Thanks a lot